# I want to post comment using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to post comment using jquery ajax and at the same time fetch posted comments using jquery ajax. Can anybody help me with jquery ajax?

Comment: What have you done so far??? .share the code here

Comment: Search for _jQuery ajax post tutorial_  or read the documentation - then come back and read the [help] and THEN ask

Comment: well i know how to post the comment to my php code but following that i need to fetch the comments posted

Comment: @RahulBanerjee If you know how to post the comment using ajax then what is the problem with retrieving the posts

Comment: well right now my code is coming in php in a loop

Comment: `echo ' <div class="comment">
                            <div class="user_pic_comment" style="background-image: url(/img/base/general.png)"></div>
                            <div class="container_comment">
                                <h4>'.$comm['fname'].' '.$comm['lname'].':</h4>
                                <p>'.$comm['comment'].'</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>'; `

Comment: how can i do the same with jquery get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is not very clear, you should have explained further what you need and give sample code of what you have so far.

I Hope this helps

HTML Code

```
<div id='old_comment'></div>
<textarea id='comment'></textarea>
<button id = 'btn'>Post Comment</button>
```

Jquery Code

```
$("document").ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(postComent);

});

function postComent(){
    $("#old_comment").html("posting comment ...");  
    $.ajax({
        url : 'url to php script',
        data : {
            comment : $("#comment").val()
        },
        datatype : "json",
        type : 'post',
        success : function(result) {
                $("#old_comment").html(result);
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("Error reaching the server. Check your connection");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("connecting");                             
mysql_select_db("my_db")or die("database");
$com = $_POST['comment'];

$query = "INSERT INTO comments(comment) VALUES('".$com."')";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("connecting")                           
mysql_select_db("my_db")or die("database");
$sql = "SELECT comment FROM comment";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = "";
        while($row = $res->fetch_row()){
                $result .= $row[0]."<br/>";
        }   
        echo $result;
?>
```

Database structure

```
Create database my_db;
Create table comments int id auto_increment, varchar(255) comment not null;
```

Comment: yes now it is clear... thank you